# How to tell Firefox to render various text files directly, rather than asking for external application?

Tags: macos, firefox, file-association

When navigating to various pages that are in a text-based format, such as source code, .tex/.sty files, unix configuration files, &c, Firefox often —I think whenever it can determine the text file's MIME type— ask for an external application to render them.  How can I tell Firefox to just render all such pages as plain text without external assistance?

I'm using Firefox 3.5.10 on Mac Os 10.4.

Comment: This is a long-standing issue - almost 10 years now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no sign of this feature being built into the browser, but there is an extension for this:

[Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207/) should do what you want.

Comment: Bingo!  One hour turnaround - my best SU experience yet - thank you!